# grunt: how to generate jshint output as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, jshint

I'm trying to run jshint using grunt. This works, but now I would like the output to be HTML. Here is my grunt file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        jshint: {
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/*.js']
            , options: {
                //reporter: 'jslint'
                reporter:'checkstyle'
                , reporterOutput: 'jshint.html'
            }
         }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
};
```

Running this grunt taks, the output is in XML. Any suggestion how to turn this into something that outputs HTML ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write a custom reporter. Check the jshint docs on writing custom reporters: http://jshint.com/docs/reporters/ Then you can specify the path to the reporter with:

```
options: {
  reporter: '/path/to/custom/html/reporter',
  reporterOutput: 'jshint.html'
}
```

Comment: So, has someone written such a reporter ? It should be pretty straightforward to do so I'd rather use an existing one instead of trying to reimplement it.

Comment: I haven't seen an existing HTML reporter. Just XML and JSON mostly.

Comment: You could check this one: [jshint-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jshint-html-reporter).
I used to show the reports in CI builds and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

> You can use jshint reporter from nodejs

This generates output in HTML

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-html-reporter

Include this in your GruntFile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        options: {
            reporter: require('jshint-html-reporter'),
            reporterOutput: 'jshint-report.html'
        },
        target: ['file.js']
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);
```